# TSQL merge: <WHEN NOT MATCHED> doesn't skip duplicate

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, merge-statement

I used the following code to update or Insert record from one table to another but the insert statement doesn't skip when duplicate record. How can i bypass that?

I get the following error. I want to skip duplicate record and insert the new

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 6 Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_MIBOMD_KEY_0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.MIBOMD'. The duplicate key value is ( , 0, 1). The statement has
>   been terminated.

```
MERGE [MIBOMD] AS TARGET
USING [whl] AS SOURCE 


ON (TARGET.[bomItem] = SOURCE.ItemID AND TARGET.bomEntry = SOURCE.bomEntry AND TARGET.bomRev = SOURCE.rev)

WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.bomEntry = SOURCE.bomEntry 
AND TARGET.partId <> SOURCE.partid THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.partId = SOURCE.partid

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (partId,bomEntry, srcLoc, qty, lead) 
VALUES (SOURCE.partid, SOURCE.bomEntry, 'R14SDS', SOURCE.qty, SOURCE.lead);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your source (`[whl]`) does not have duplicates?

Comment: @tarheel no, because the primary keys on `[whl]` are `ItemID` and `PartID`.  there are multiple or duplicate  `Item ID`s only but  `ItemID + Part ID` are unique

Comment: @tarheel no, because the primary keys on [whl] are ItemID and PartID. there are multiple or duplicate Item IDs only but ItemID + Part ID is unique

Comment: Could you add some Sample data to your question? it is not clear from your code or your description that where the problem is....

Comment: @M.Ali i added two images at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Which columns form the primary key of your source table `dbo.MIBOMD`?

Comment: @sstan `bomItem + bomRev+bomEntry`

Comment: So there are multiple ItemID and you only matching on ItemID and you wonder why you are getting duplicates?

Comment: @user6305775 You are only matching ON (TARGET.[bomItem] = SOURCE.ItemID) and there is no bomRev

Comment: I tired too and clean up the question with table def IN the question.  And for the second time you are NOT inserting a bomRev.  That blank value ( , 0, 3) is not a clue?

Comment: `UPDATE SET TARGET.partId = SOURCE.partid` - that's what produces duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, the uniqueness in the source is guaranteed by `ItemID + PartID`.
Meanwhile, you are matching by source `(ItemID,bomEntry,rev)=target.(bomItem,bomEntry,bomRev)`.

It is entirely possible that you will have something with the same set of `(ItemID,bomEntry,rev)` in the source but have two different `PartID`.

Also, among the `INSERTed` columns you specified, there is no `bomRev,bomItem`.

Are there default constraints on those columns? Will they guarantee uniqueness?